# React JS error: this.state.data.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and this threw up while trying to map some data from API. I have set the state to an array but still this error comes up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends Component {
    state = {
        articles: [],
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=ef678d80cc70495184c2bf95d4576c9b')
            .then(response => {
                const articles = response.data;
                this.setState({ articles });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
           <ul>
            {this.state.articles.map(article => <li><a href={`${article.url}`}>{article.title}</a></li>)}
           </ul>
       </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: `this.state.data.map` is not even in your code, you sure its the right code posted?

Comment: When you get .map is not a function error this usuall means `data` is not what you expect. In this case, data would have to be an array, and if map is not present - it's not that (somehow, due to a bug). Next time something like this happens try doing `console.log(articles)` for example in the axios callback, or using the React Devtools to see prop types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
const articles = response.data;
```

to

```
const articles = response.data.articles;
```

Its because the api returns an JSON Output with response in articles key.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends Component {
        state = {
            articles: [],
        }
     componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=ef678d80cc70495184c2bf95d4576c9b')
        .then(response => {
            const articles = response;
            this.setState({articles:articles.articles});
        }) }

render() {
    return (
       <div>
           <ul>
            {this.state.articles.map(article => 
            <li><a href={`${article.url}`}>{article.title}</a>
            </li>)}
           </ul>
       </div>
    ) }

}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends Component {
        state = {
            articles: [],
             flag:false
        }
     componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=ef678d80cc70495184c2bf95d4576c9b')
        .then(response => {
            const articles = response.data;
            this.setState({articles,flag:true});
        }) }

render() {
    let data = flag === false?"Loading...":this.state.articles.map(article => <li><a href={`${article.url}`}>{article.title}</a></li>)
    return (
       <div>
           <ul>
            {data}
           </ul>
       </div>
    ) }

}

export default Test;
```